# g++ options, from Mac to cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin

I am trying to run this code a file called make-simple.sh from cygwin with `sh make-simple.sh`
This file contains the following code needed to compile a main.cpp file

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -c -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O3 -fno-tree-pre -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -msse3 -mssse3 -I/usr/include/nite -I/usr/include/ni -DXN_SSE -o Release/main.o ../SingleControl/main.cpp
g++ -o ./SingleControl ./Release/main.o ./Release/signal_catch.o ./Release/kbhit.o -arch i386 -arch x86_64  -L../Bin -lOpenNI -lXnVNite
```

I think that this works only on Mac. Is it possible to make it work under Windows with cygwin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass only a single `-arch` value.

EDIT: or better, none at all. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -c -O3 -fno-tree-pre -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -msse3 -I/usr/include/nite -I/usr/include/ni -DXN_SSE -o Release/main.o ../SingleControl/main.cpp
g++ -o ./SingleControl ./Release/main.o ./Release/signal_catch.o ./Release/kbhit.o -L../Bin -lOpenNI -lXnVNite
```

Comment: Still getting the "g++: x86_64: No such file or directory" error. Maybe is not a Mac to Windows issue as I thought. Thank you

Comment: You need to remove *both* the option **and** the value.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
g++ -c -O3 -fno-tree-pre -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -msse3 -mssse3 -I/usr/include/nite -I/usr/include/ni -DXN_SSE -o Release/main.o ../SingleControl/main.cpp
g++ -o ./SingleControl ./Release/main.o ./Release/signal_catch.o ./Release/kbhit.o -L../Bin -lOpenNI -lXnVNite

Comment: the error is now: No such file or directorycpp
g++: no input files
./Release/main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized